# Customise a single list item

Tags: css

I've got a list

```
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
nav li{
    background-colour:#555;
    height:15px;
}
```

My question is how can I customise only the the `<li>Tea</li>`

EDIT:
I'm looking for a way to have `<li>Tea</li>` as `background-color:#999; height:25px;` and all others to be `background-color:#555; height:15px;`.

Comment: You could use `nth-child()` or `nth-of-type()` selectors to select the 2nd `li` but do you have a specific pattern?

Comment: Use a css class to target your element. That's the "standard" way of doing things

Comment: @Harry thanks. what if I specify a class for the `li` I need?

Comment: @Becky Sure you can, that's another easier way to do it.

Comment: @Harry is there a way to override `nav li{}` withtout `!important` ?

Comment: @Becky: Yes, you can. Just make the selector more specific. You can read more about specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:nth-child` selector

For example if you want to select second `li`

```
nav li:nth-child(2) {
    background-colour:#555;
    height:15px;
}
```

See [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) and [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) for more details

**UPDATE**

As OP commented all `li` should be same except a single one. In that case use selector to select all `li` apply some property then select that single one which you want to be different. See below

```
nav li {
    background-colour:#555;
    height:15px;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:#999; 
    height:25px;
}
```

Or you can assign some class to it then style it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child()` selector and also change `background-colour:#555;` to `background-color:#555;`

```css
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:#555;
    height:15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

According to your comment,you also apply the general style to all your `list-items` then override the style of your `nth-child(2)` li like

```css
ul li {
    background-color:#555;
    height:15px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:#999; 
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
       <li>Coffee</li>
       <li>Tea</li>
       <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `id` of the item list

```css
#foo {
        background: black;
        height:15px;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
       <li>Coffee</li>
       <li id="foo">Tea</li>
       <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`nav li:first-child{
    background-colour:#555;
    height:15px;
}`

**Or adding a class to each li**

```
<ul>
   <li class="1">Coffee</li>
   <li class="2">Tea</li>
   <li class="3">Milk</li>
</ul>
```